# Strange text on Internet Explorer's title bar

Tags: internet-explorer, virus

I have an XP machine in which my Internet Explorer's title bar says "Lord rahul cool."

Example: if you open google.com, IE's title bar says 'Google - LORD RAHUL COOL' earlier it was like 'Google - Microsoft Internet Explorer'

I have scanned the machine with AVG free which found nothing, which suggests that this is not a virus.

What is causing this, and how can I remove it?

Comment: its not a virus , most probably a friend playing a prank .  follow the registry change suggested by user395072 , should help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To Add a Custom Internet Explorer Window Title
Using Registry Editor, add a String value named Window Title to the following key in the registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main
```

The data value is the title you want to appear on the Internet Explorer window.

I would suggest add here "Lord Pallavan IE Explorer" :) , kidding

NOTE: In Windows NT, the value should be of type REG_SZ instead of String.
To Remove a Custom Internet Explorer Window Title
Using Registry Editor, delete the following value in the registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\Window Title
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to revert the window title (taken from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/176497)

- Use the Registry Editor to delete the key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\Window Title`